# Como manter a ordem dos checkboxes selecionados e enviar pelo form para outra página

Tags: php, formulário, checkbox

Eu tenho um código na `page1.php` onde eu tenho uma matriz de checkboxes preenchida com dados MySQL através de uma consulta. Eu consigo enviar o valor da checkboxes marcadas para a `page2.php`. Mas eu quero que a ordem seja a mesma em que os checkboxes foram selecionados.

Minha intenção é mostrar na `page2.php` o que o usuário selecionou na `page1.php`, seguindo a ordem que ele clicou.

MODIFICADO: Bom, consegui criar a lista e mandar via form. O problema agora é colocar uma virgula entre os números. Sei que este deve ser o problema mais fácil de resolver, mas não estou conseguindo ainda.

A SQL Query esta ficando assim, por exemplo:

> SELECT * FROM emp WHERE id IN (7,9,30) ORDER BY FIELD (id,
>   30 9 7)

**page1.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var listCheckedOptions = [];

function addToList(checkObj, outputObjID) {
    //Remove from array if the element already in.
    if (listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj) >= 0) {
        listCheckedOptions.splice(listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj), 1);
    } 

    listCheckedOptions.push(checkObj);

    document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = ""; //Clean textarea
    document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = listCheckedOptions.map(function (o) {
        return o.value;
    }).join('\r\n'); //Add to textarea
    if (!checkObj.checked) checkObj.nextSibling.querySelector('span').innerHTML = '';
    listCheckedOptions.forEach(function (el, i) {
        var span = el.nextSibling.querySelector('span').innerHTML = i + 1;
    });

    return;
}
</script>

    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM imoveis";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
    ?>

    <form action="page2.php" method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="Create" id="enviarButton"/></td>

    <br><br>

    <table border="1">
        <?
        $i = 0;

        echo "<tr>";

             while($imovel = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                $name = $imovel['emp'];
                $id = $imovel['id'];

    ?>   

            <td>
                <?=$name;?><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="op_imovel[]" value="<?=$id;?>" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')">
            </td>
    <?
               $i++;
               if(($i % 3) == 0){
                      echo "</tr><tr>";
                      }
               }

    mysql_close();

    ?>

    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="txt1" id="txt1">

    </form>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
  $checkbox = $_POST['op_imovel'];
  $lista = $_POST['txt1'];

  if (is_array($checkbox) && count($checkbox) > 0){
        $res = '';
        $tot = count($checkbox) - 1;
        for ($y = 0; $y <= $tot; $y++) {

            $res .=$checkbox[$y];

            if ($y < $tot)
                $res .= ",";
        }

    }


  $query = "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE id IN ($res) ORDER BY FIELD (id, $lista)";
  $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
?>

<br>


<div align="center">

        <table border="1">

<?
$i = 0;
echo "<tr>";

    if (is_array($checkbox) && count($checkbox) > 0){
        while($imovel = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

            $name = ($imovel['emp']);
?>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <?= $name;?>
                    </p>

                </td>
<?
           $i++;
           if(($i % 3) == 0){
                  echo "</tr><tr>";
           }


        }       

    }   
?>      


</div>

<?  mysql_close(); ?>
```

Comment: O que a função `setChecks()` faz? A sua função jQuery manipula um *array* que nunca é usado. Da forma que está `$_POST['check_order']` na page2.php recebe todos os IDs, pois todos os campos *hidden* são enviados

Comment: A função setChecks() estava ai para verificar a quantidade de seleções pelo usuário, mas não preciso dela neste caso (ja tirei do código). Não sei programar em JQuery, mas estou tentando entender. A minha função JQuery deve pegar os values dos checkboxes ou dos campos hidden? Meus checkboxes devem continuar sendo arrays? preciso mesmo dos checkboxes e dos campos hidden? Desculpe tantas perguntas, mas estou bem confuso com isso.

Comment: Já encontrei o código certo e já consegui fazer funcionar. Preciso apenas colocar virgulas entre os números. Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Problema resolvido, era so tirar '\r\n' do .join()